# What is the biblical basis for Jesus being God incarnate?

Tags: life-of-jesus, biblical-basis, christology, incarnation, divinity

In [John 17:3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2017:3&version=NIV) it says that Jesus called the Father the "only true God" and called himself sent by the Father.

Also, in [Matthew 4:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%204:10;&version=NIV;), Jesus himself says to:

> ‘Worship the Lord your God, and serve him only.’`

What is the biblical basis for accepting Jesus as not only divine, but "god in the flesh"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity)

Comment: @Jonathon Byrd. This question may be answered without addressing the doctrine of trinity. Binitarianism teaches Jesus is as God, but the Holy Spirit is not a distinct person of the Godhead. A different hermenuetics is required to answer the Trinity question.

Comment: See also: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/does-jesus-ever-claim-to-be-god-or-the-son-of-god/4467#4467

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For the quick answer to your question, see **[John 1:1, 14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%201:1,14&version=ESV)**.

But really, this is a simple matter of the transitive property.

**Jesus forgives sin** ([Mark 2:1-12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark%202:1-12&version=ESV)): It's a non-debated point of doctrine that only God can forgive sins. It's easy for the modern reader to marvel at the miracle without realizing the greater significance of Jesus' statement. Jesus here uses the miracle to refute the accusations of blasphemy (See [Psalm 130:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20130:4&version=ESV); [Isa. 43:25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isa%2043:25&version=ESV); [Dan. 9:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=dan%209:9&version=ESV)).

**Jesus is eternal** ([John 8:53-59](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=joh%208:53-59&version=ESV)): The Jews weren't about to stone Him because they didn't like what He said, but because He was saying that He is God. I AM is His name. At the very least, Jesus is claiming to be no ordinary man, for how else could He claim to exist before Abraham? Also, see [John 1:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=joh%201:2&version=ESV); [17:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=joh%2017:5&version=ESV); [Rev. 1:8](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rev%201:8&version=ESV)

**Jesus is creator**: See [John 1:3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=joh%201:3&version=ESV), [Col. 1:16,17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Col.%201:16-17&version=ESV), [Hebrews 1:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%201:2&version=ESV).

**Jesus is rightly worshiped**: Jesus is worshiped throughout the Gospels (recorded seven times in Matthew alone: [2:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%202:11&version=ESV); [8:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%208:2&version=ESV); [9:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%209:18&version=ESV); [14:33](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%2014:33&version=ESV); [15:25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%2015:25&version=ESV); [28:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%2028:9&version=ESV); [28:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt%2028:17&version=ESV)) and it is not recorded that he stopped them. See also [Philippians 2:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=phil%202:10&version=ESV); [Heb 1:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=heb%201:6&version=ESV), [Rev. 5:12-14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rev.%205:12-14&version=ESV), when all of creation and the heavenly angels worship Him.

Comment: "how else could He claim to exist before Abraham?" Easy - notional pre-existence. See https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/jesus-pre-existence-literal-or-ideal

Comment: I went through the notional pre-existence.  Very interesting view. Although we can see the Unitarian bias in it 

Answer (score 14):

The chapter below is titled "The Government of the Promised Son" and seems to answer your question regarding Jesus, the Son, being God.

Isaiah 9:6

> "For unto us a Child  is born, **Unto us a Son is given**; And the government will be upon His shoulder. And the government will be upon His shoulder. **And His name will be called** Wonderful, Counselor, **Mighty God**, **Everlasting Father**, Prince of Peace."

Also, in prophetic ministry, Hosea speaks out the word of the Lord in 13:4;

> "Yet I am the Lord your God ever since the land of Egypt, and you shall know no God but Me. For there is **no Savior besides Me**."

Yet, in Luke 2:11 God sent an angel to announce to shepherds, "For there is born to you this day in the city of David **a Savior, who is Christ the Lord**."

Since our Father said to Hosea, "For there is **no Savior besides Me**.", and He also sent His angel to announce the birth of the **a Savior**, one has to conclude that the Father and the Son are one.

Answer (score 4):

> Philippians 2:5-7
>   New International Version (NIV)
>
> 5 In your relationships with one another, have the same mindset as Christ Jesus:
>
> 6 Who, ***being in very nature God,***
>       did not consider ***equality with God*** something to be used to his own advantage;
>
> 7 rather, he made himself nothing
>       by taking the very nature of a servant,
>       ***being made in human likeness***.

This verse clearly shows that Jesus God was manifest in the flesh. Now let us deal with John 17:3.

John 17:3  And this is life eternal, that they might know thee ***the only true God***, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent.

the parallel to this verse 1 John 5:20-21

1 Jn 5:20  And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an understanding, that we may know him that is true, and we are in him that is true, even in his Son Jesus Christ. This is ***the true God***, and eternal life. 
1Jn 5:21  Little children, ***keep yourselves from idols***. Amen.

John 1:1 is commonly used to prove Jesus is God but then if Jesus is God then according to John 17:3 He is a false God. There is no escaping this fact. A true scholar would then try to reconcile the two apparent contradictions. Therefore we conclude for Christ's sake and the the sake of the Gospel that true God being talked about here is the triune God. Jesus is not excluded here for He is part of the Triune Godhead. if the true God is the Father only the we have a problem. You are to share your opinion as always.

Lets also deal with Mat 14:10 which says:

> ‘Worship the Lord your God, and serve him only.’`

Again as a scholar you have to compare other scripture with other scriptures spiritual against spiritual.

> Rom_1:1  Paul, a ***servant of Jesus Christ***, called to be an apostle, separated unto the gospel of God,
>
> Jud_1:1  Jude, ***the servant of Jesus Christ***, and brother of James, to them that are sanctified by God the Father, and preserved in Jesus Christ, and called:

Now where the apostles wrong in their serving of Jesus Christ who is God (John 1:1)? of course not. Once the triune Godhead is established many contradictions can be solved. Just think of a world without this solution...

Comment: Mmm the truine God.  Any article where this is greatly expressed ?

Comment: It is interesting to note that the message of the apostles was never that everyone should start believing in a "triune" God or else. Nor was there any emphasis on the divinity of Jesus in the early church letters

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the strongest case for the deity of Messiah is from the gospels, John 20, where Thomas sees the risen Messiah, touches the nail prints in his hands, and finally believes, exclaiming to Messiah,

> My Lord, and my God!

Messiah's response to Thomas is telling; he affirms by saying,

> You believe only because you've seen. Blessed are those that believe without seeing.

Comment: But in the same chapter Jesus said at John 20:17  I am ascending to MY Father and your Father and to MY God and your God.’”   So Jesus has a "God" just a Thomas has a God!  As prayer is a act of worship then in John Ch 17 Jesus prayed to His God1

Comment: You're noting that there is a distinction between God and Messiah. That's true. And yet, God and Messiah are one - and in Revelation, we see a single throne: the "throne of God and the Lamb." This suggests there is some mystery and even nuance involved with the divinity of Messiah, and yet, the disciples and apostles prayed to, worshiped, and honored Messiah as God. Either that's idolatry, or Messiah is God in the flesh.

Comment: What you note is not in harmony with Scripture:  (Philippian 2:7 . . .No, but he EMPTIED himself and took a slave’s form and became HUMAN.

Comment: What's not in harmony with Scripture? Revelation 5 paints a picture of a single throne in heaven, the throne of God and the Lamb; the Father and Messiah. It shows, as does the gospels, that people worship *him*, singular. Again, there is distinction between Messiah and the Father, and yet, Messiah and the Father are one. The gospels, the epistles, and Revelation show this view.

Answer (score 1):

We know that Jesus is God incarnate because of his self-knowledge which is shown both in his words and in his actions.

Jesus said that He existed as the Son of Man prior to His Incarnation ( John 6:62).

Jesus said that he is in existence even before Abraham came into existence ( John 8:58).

Jesus said that he is one with the Father in terms of ability ( John 10:28-30).

Jesus commanded to baptize disciples in the name of the Trinity ( Matthew 28:19).

The writers of the New Testament are Jesus' disciples and based on their experience with him, they recorded his words and deeds that are necessary for the teaching and edification of the church.

The Apostle John wrote that "In the beginning was the Word[ Jesus] and the Word was with God[ the Father] and the Word was God" ( John 1:1).

Paul wrote that Jesus originally existed " in very nature, God" ( Philippians 2:6 NIV ) and that Jesus is " our great God" ( Titus 2:13 KJV).

The writer of Hebrews wrote that Jesus is the "exact imprint of his nature"( Hebrews 1:3 ESV ).

Peter wrote that Jesus is "our God and Savior" ( 2 Peter 1:1).