# All the references where Jesus is offered worship

Tags: life-of-jesus, worship, jehovahs-witnesses

What are all the references to the instances where where Jesus is offered worship in the Bible?

I am raising this question because some of my friends from some specific denomintations believe only Jehavah as the only God. Quoting references where Jesus is being worshipped in the Bible can help me prove that Jesus is God and will help me partially in explaining trinity.

Comment: Compare: [Should we avoid "refute this"-type questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1264) (That question is also about Jehovah's Witnesses, incidentally.)

Comment: Premiere Christian radio just had a series of two debates between a Jehovah's witness and a member of a jw outreach organization on the program 'unbelievable'.

Comment: For an answer to the wider implied question here, please see: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/does-jesus-ever-claim-to-be-god-or-the-son-of-god

Comment: You're going to have difficulty using these passages to prove that Jehovah is not the only God.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - Jesus Christ is Jehovah. He states about him "I am" and when He pronouces it it makes his captors fall to the ground. So the name of God "I am" is the name of Jesus, not only of Father.

At least two fragments I can come up with now:

That at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, of things in heaven, and things in earth, and things under the earth; (Philippians 2, 10)

And when I saw him, I fell at his feet as dead. And he laid his right hand upon me, saying unto me, Fear not; I am the first and the last (Revelation 1, 17, note that unlike angel from the same book, Christ doesn't forbid falling at His feet)

Comment: And, when the crippled man was presented to him through the roof, the first thing he said was "I forgive your sins."  Only God can forgive sins, and when the religious leaders started to object, he asked, which is easier, to forgive sins or to heal, and then proceeded to heal him too.  In other words, he presented himself as God in many ways throughout his ministry.

Comment: *Cogito ergo sum.* I refuse to read any special meaning into "I am".

Comment: @thursdaysgeek. He said, "[Your sins are forgiven](http://bible.cc/mark/2-5.htm)." Nothing about doing it himself.

Comment: @TRiG - the religious leaders considered his statement to be blasphemous, since only God can forgive sins.  And if you read more of the statement, he goes on to say "Which is easier: to say, ‘Your sins are forgiven,’ or to say, ‘Get up and walk’?  But I want you to know that the Son of Man has authority on earth to forgive sins.”  He certainly WAS claiming to do it himself.

Comment: You might want to add Thomas, who calls Jesus "my Lord and my God".

Answer (score 2):

**There are 10 instances in Matthew alone** where Jesus appears to be worshipped by people. Matthew 2:2, 8, 11 ; 8:2; 9:18; 14:33; 15:25; 20:20; 28:9, 17. Other examples include Luke 24:52 and John 9:38. This is important because only God should be worshipped, as is commanded by God in the Old Testament, God through the NT writers, Jesus in the Gospels, and angels (see Revelation 19:10).

Additionally, Thomas calls Jesus "My Lord and my God" in John 20:28-29. Luke 7:36-50 details a woman worshipping Jesus, pouring perfume on His feet, washing them with her hair and kissing them. [Here is a reference with more discussion and examples.](https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-worshipped.html) I will need to do more searching to find others.

I found the list of 10 references in Matthew in a journal article in *Biblica* titled ["The Worship of Jesus in the Gospel of Matthew."](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/42615100.pdf) Searching on [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org) enough may provide more catalogued references. I also have a (work-in-progress) excel sheet that I keep with over 150 verses from the Gospels in various categories that support Jesus' deity and another 150 verses from the other books of the Bible. Categories such as His titles, Jewish blasphemous response, divine attributes, references as Son of God, his authority, the I am statements, and more. I haven't finished the being worshipped category. Hopefully I can update this when I do.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is far from being as easy as some would wish it to be because the English word “worship” (as with the Hebrew and Greek words) have shades of meaning according to context, and who is being spoken of or addressed:-

> Google Dictionary  - Worship
>   noun
>   1.  1.
>   the feeling or expression of reverence and adoration for a deity.
>   "worship of the Mother Goddess"
>   synonyms:   reverence, revering, worshipping, veneration, venerating, adoration, adoring, -olatry, devotion, praise, thanksgiving, praising, praying to, glorification, glorifying, glory, exaltation, exalting, extolment, extolling, homage, respect, honour, honouring, esteem; More
>
> 2.
>   BRITISH
>   used in addressing or referring to an important or high-ranking person, especially a magistrate or mayor.
>   "we were soon joined by His Worship the Mayor"
>
> verb
>   1.  1.
>   show reverence and adoration for (a deity).
>   "the Maya built jungle pyramids to worship their gods"
>   synonyms:   revere, reverence, venerate, pay homage to, honour, adore, praise, pray to, bow down before, glorify, exalt, extol; 
>   be devoted to, dote on, love, hold dear, cherish, treasure, admire, esteem, adulate, idolize, deify, hero-worship, lionize, have a high regard for, hold in high regard, hold in esteem, hold in awe, look up to; 
>   informalbe wild about, put on a pedestal;  archaicmagnify; rarelaud
>   "they do not worship pagan gods"

In the above we see a brief overview of the **shades** of meaning in “worship.”

Examples.
Is all praise Worship?
We can praise a person or God for doing something good.  In the first instance is a way of saying well done, and in the second, but the second is also an act of Worship.

I all adoration worship?
We can adore our wife, husband, children, God.  This is an expression of our love in all cases, but in the last its an act of worship.

In the scriptures we are told to honour our God and parents.  We give honour to our God and parents its love and respect etc. etc., but in God’s case its also worship.

The Hebrew and Greek term rendered “worship” basically means to ‘bow down,’ ‘fall down,’ ‘prostrate.’    “Bow down” is good to make a point in that when before a royal person or a judge in court all people bow down to them or in Hebrew “Hishtachawah;” and in Greek it would be “Proskyneo” which can be translated “worship.”   In this case it cannot mean worship as it is done to humans so in must be act in a lesser way, an act is respect of the Office that the person hold.  It would be an act of “obeisance” (see below) not worship, but if done to God it becomes an act of “worship”!

> Google - obeisance
>   noun
>   1. deferential respect.
>   "they paid obeisance to the Prince"
>   synonyms:   respect, homage, worship, adoration, reverence, veneration, respectfulness, honour, submission, deference
>   "they paid obeisance to the Prince"
>     a gesture expressing deferential respect, such as a bow or curtsy.
>   plural noun: obeisances"
>   she made a deep obeisance"
>   synonyms:   bow, curtsy, bob, genuflection, salaam, salutation; 
>   namaskar; 
>   historicalkowtow;
>   archaicreverence
>   "she made a deep obeisance"

“Obeisance” is what is given to Jesus because of his Offices and Agency in Jehovah God’s arrangement for the salvation to mankind etc. etc.-

> NWT  Matthew 2:2  “Where is the one born king of the Jews? For we saw his star when we were in the East, and we have come to do ***obeisance*** to him.”