# Is the Holy Spirit offered worship at any instance?

Tags: biblical-basis, pneumatology

This question is similar to this one except that its on Holy Spirit:
[All the references where Jesus is offered worship](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/all-the-references-where-jesus-is-offered-worship)

Is there any reference in the Bible where the Holy Spirit is offered worship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a reference in the Bible to worshipping the Spirit specifically and I can only think of one reference where worshipping the Father  is specifically mentioned (John 4:21). Almost all references simply mean worshipping the Father, Son and Holy Spirit as they are one.

Yet we can know that each person of the Trinity has a distinct operation in the relation to the other persons. When the Bible refers to ‘God’ in general, then no particular person of the trinity is being identified.  Almost all references to worship in the Bible are not specific to any particular person in the trinity, therefore by definition all three persons are being worshipped in almost every case.

However when any special impression is made of the special property of any person in the words of our worship; then the worship is drawing attention to that work as assigned peculiarly to that person.   For example when the Palms or other songs of worship are sung it the words refer to the original will behind the creation, we might be said to be worshipping the Father.  If mention is made of Gods powerful word in the creation, it could be said we are worshipping the Son.  If we mentioned the perfection and finished works of creation itself we could be said to be worshipping the Spirit.