# Did Jesus say "worship me, I am God"

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, trinity, worship

Is there a verse in the Bible states that Jesus himself said to his people that he is God and must be worshipped?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Good point.  In His claim to be God, Jesus asserted that He ought to be worshiped.

Comment: The Old Testament prophesied that there would be "a Son given" who would be called "Mighty God" (Isaiah 9:6-7).  Because Jesus is the Son who was given, He is God and is worthy of worship.  Also, Revelation 1 is pretty clear that Jesus is God Almighty, the Alpha and Omega, the Beginning and the End, the First and the Last.

Comment: It's the same question. If Jesus said he was God, it doesn't take a separate command to know that we should worship him.

Comment: The other answers show that your question is based on a false premise: Jesus **did** say that he was God -- and he proved it with miracles, not least the resurrection. He wasn't just some crackpot saying he was God. He was God. God must be worshipped. We worship Jesus as God.

Comment: To pre-empt the discussion cutoff, there is already a chat room devoted to this. Let's use it. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14411/discussion-between-djclayworth-and-zohal

Comment: **NO**, Jesus implicitly didn't say "I'm God worship me", but notions are deduced.

Answer (score 0):

In John 20: 28-29 and Revelation 1:17 Jesus allows people to worship him.  Further, Jesus never says to not worship him.  So, it is allowed, but not forced.

See related questions:

[All the references where Jesus is offered worship](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/all-the-references-where-jesus-is-offered-worship?rq=1)

[Why is it important for people who believe in Trinity that Jesus is God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27728/why-is-it-important-for-people-who-believe-in-trinity-that-jesus-is-god?rq=1)

This question was also answered on one of your previous questions:

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/why-do-christians-worship-jesus?rq=1

Comment: Can you tell me when did people start worshiping Jesus?

Comment: @Zohal They started while he was still alive -- Matthew 16:16. They continued immediately after the resurrection -- John 20:28.

Comment: What proof is there that he appeared after resurrection? Didnt he resurrect/Go to heaven so why would he come back to earth AGAIN?

Comment: He came back to earth to fulfill the Messianic prophecies in the Old Testament.  In the Old Testament the Messiah is prophesied to come once as a suffering servant (Maschiach ben Yosef), and then again as a conquering king (Maschiach ben David) when the dead will be ressurrected.  Some proof is that Jesus knew things about the disciples that an impostor would not know, such as how Peter betrayed him before the crucifixion; Jesus prophesied before dying about his resurrection; Paul's vision of Jesus taught Paul exactly the same doctrine that Jesus taught to Peter.

Comment: I can't comment on the original question due to lack of points, but it is incorrect to claim that Jesus said he is God.  He says things that can imply he is God, but Jesus never explicitly says he is God.  Jesus does this on purpose.  His sayings are only understood by those who want to listen.  Those who don't can ignore him.