# How many times Jesus was montioned in both of Holy Bible and Holy Quran?

Tags: bible, reference-request, words-of-jesus, quran

Is there someone here give me the number of citations of Jesus in the original version of the Holy Bible ? I say to you in the Holy Quran He is mentioned 32 times and we have a Surah called **Merry** which means **Meriam** in Arabic language  Mother of Jesus ? Is there the same in the Holy Bible ?

**Note**: Am afraid that the number of citations of Jesus in Holy Quran is greater than its citation in the Holy Bible

**Edit** I have edited the question without changing its meaning such that I want exactly the number of citation in the original Holy Bible not in the corrupted version.

Comment: Hey just wrote an answer but didn't see you edit. **What do you consider the *corrupted* version?** Virtually all Christians agree on at least 66 books, and those are where my references come from. Perhaps you mean in the original languages and not English translations?

Comment: @ninthamigo, ok you may ask priest here to show you exactly what does it mean "Corrupted version "

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm familiar with claims that the bible is corrupted from Islamic Apologists, but not from priests. I happen to accept there are a large number of *mistakes* in some copies that have no bearing on the meaning, and virtually none of which were intentionally (as the word 'corrupted' implies), but this is not corruption. Furthermore, they do not affect the number of times Jesus' name is used. Even Muslims accept printed errors like this in the Qur'an without calling them corruptions: https://bible-quran.com/arabic-quran-cairo/

Comment: @ninthamigo, There is difference between translation in the context of language by means translation of any version without changing the meaning , But Holy bible challenge many corruptions from priests  to get some of their particular benefits and service, I can give u many arguments and testament in holy Bible which make corruption, And I show you that is not the word of God ,

Comment: @ninthamigo, The word of God is the original version which were dropped over Prophet Jesus christian, And am willing to share you many debates between christian and Islam  , Many contradictions were apperaed in holybible but no one founded in the Holy Quran, The difference between muslim and Christian is that muslim believes with all holy books which dropped  over prophets and messengers (original version of them ) , The only book on earth which were not and is not and will not make corruption is the holyQuran,

Comment: And christian bielive only with new version of Holy bible each year even that book become has infinity many versions with infinity many meaning

Comment: Since most Christians are not mind-readers, it would be very helpful to precisely define what you mean by the two expressions, *original* and *corrupted* Bible.

Comment: Christians don't believe the Bible is corrupted. If you want to talk about the corrupted Bible go to [islam.se].

Answer (score 5):

In order to avoid arguments about corrupted versions and exactly what consistutues a mention of Jesus, let us cut straight to key point. You write:

> I am afraid that the number of citations of Jesus in Holy Quran Greater than its citation in Holy Bible

**That is unquestionably not true**

Four books of the Bible (the books of Matthew, Mark, Luke and John) are life stories of Jesus, and talk about virtually nothing else. They are called the "Gospels" and make up about 82400 words. **That is more words than there are in the Quran.**

Another 23 books of the Bible talk extensively about Jesus. They, together with the Gospels, make up what is called the "New Testament". They have a total of around 100,000 words.

The number of explicit mentions of Jesus in the Bible (not counting ones where one of his titles is used instead of his name) is about a thousand, more than twenty times the number in the Quran.

The amount of the Holy Bible talking about Jesus is much more than the entirety of the Quran. This is unsurprising. Jesus is the Central figure of the Christian scriptures and the Christian religion. "Christian" comes from "Christ", which is a title of Jesus.

Comment: Could u give me any testament from holy Bible where Jesus christian said to the world " Am God worship me " ? I want it by this expression ?

Comment: I answered this at the top of the page. In general if you have a separate question, your should write a new question - but in this case it's been asked before here, so I've given you a link to the previous one.

Comment: If you like we can give you a link to the four books of the Bible that describe Jesus' life in detail. I think you would find it helpful to read them.

Comment: I have checked all of them many years ago , the problem every year we have a new version of holybible , and I didn't find at all any testament with this expression where Jesus said to the world " Am God worship me "

Comment: I gave you the link to where Jesus says that under Daniel Stein's answer.

Comment: @zeraouliarafikYour question? "Am God worship me." God the Father stated at Hebrews 1:6, "And let all the angels of God worship Him/Jesus Christ." At Hebrews 1:8 God the Father says about His Son, "Thy Throne O God is forever and ever." Jesus never said the exact words, "I am God." Others like Thomas at John 20:28 said to Jesus, "My Lord and my God." This is a declaration of the highest form of worship. Others identified Jesus as God. 2 Peter 1:1, Titus 3:13. If Jesus had said, "I am God" would you believe Him? Why don't you believe what others declared to Jesus? Why not accept this as proof?

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you are asking this question as I enjoy inter-religious dialogue. If you are asking how many times his name is referenced, I think your count from the Qur'an may be incorrect since Jesus (Isa, ibn Maryam) is said to be used 39 times in the Qur'an [here](https://katietokhadijah.com/jesus-in-the-quran/).

Alternatively, for the Bible it depends on your translation and method of interpretation.
For example: Bible prophecy in the Old Testament (Jewish Bible) are considered references to Jesus by many New Testament Scholars (Injil etc.). Hosea 11:1

> When Israel was a child, I loved him, and out of Egypt I called my son. (NIV)

Is cited by St. Matthew in Matthew 2:15 as being ultimately about Jesus. You also must take into account different titles which refer to Jesus like Messiah or Christ. This is similar to Prophet Muhammad being called simply the Messenger of Allah, rather than being referenced by name.

In the New Testament, a largely ecumenical translation (NRSV) uses the name **Jesus** 999 times. **Christ** is used 468 times, and Messiah 66 times[.](https://www.christianbiblereference.org/faq_WordCount.htm) Some of these uses may be redundant where people say his name and title together as in "Jesus Christ" but it certainly rises above 1,000 references contra the 39 in the Qur'an.

Finally, a common name Jesus used in reference to himself was "Son of Man" which he used 82 times just in the Injil[.](https://www.biblestudytools.com/encyclopedias/isbe/son-of-man-the.html)

Comment: Do you have the origianl version of holybible ? be serious ?

Comment: An excellent and free kindle book written by Dan Wickwire is *Has the Bible Been Changed?: The Reliability of the Scriptures According to Jewish, Christian, and Islamic Sources* in which he argues that those who accept the validity of the Qur'an's preservation should not challenge the authenticity of the Bible. In 1996, the Turkish government recalled all their teaching materials which previously said the Bible was corrupted because this book was so influential and convincing See: https://www.amazon.com/Has-Bible-Been-Changed-Reliability-ebook/dp/B01I41U06A

Comment: Do u have the original version of holy bible ?

Comment: I speak English, some Arabic, and a little Spanish. The original bible was written in several languages none of which I speak: ancient Hebrew, Koine Greek, and a little bit of Aramaic. I posses several English translations which use slightly different wording but I find to virtually never disagree on meaning. 'Original' versions of the Qur'an were burned, but I have little difficulty reading current translations and accepting that the vast majority of it is unchanged. See: http://harvardhouse.com/quran_purity.htm

Comment: @zeraouliarafik There is no one original version: even the oldest copies vary.

Answer (score 0):

The number of times Jesus is mentioned in the Bible varies by translation. In the King James Version, it appears 983 times, while in the New International Version, it is mentioned 1273 times. Numbers for other words and other translations [here](https://www.christianbiblereference.org/faq_WordCount.htm).

Comment: Do you meant that you have infinity many version of holyBible ? ,The number of citation I need is in it original version not the corrupted version

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The "versions" are just different translations of the original. They are not corrupted. The differences are things like the original manuscript sometimes says "he" (when it clearly means Jesus) and a newer translation makes it say "Jesus" explicitly. Anyway, the differences are trivial. There are four whole books of the Bible that talk almost entirely about Jesus. He is the focal point of the Christian scriptures.

Comment: @DJClayworth , Have you the original bible which were dropped over Jesus christian ? and could u give me any argument from holy Bible which Jesus said to the world " Am god worship me ?

Comment: Yes, we do have the original versions of the scriptures, with some very minor variations. The second question is answered on this question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/does-jesus-ever-claim-to-be-god-or-the-son-of-god. But please don't use this site as a forum to argue.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I do not used it as argue forum but one should know the truth my friend , And I should contribute all my arguments in the same time I look to benefits from your backgrounds

Comment: We do not have the original autographs of the 4 Gospels,  What we have is over 10,000 fragments of very early copies which, apart from some minor copying errors, are all in agreement.  This makes the Gospel accounts the most well supported ancient literature by far.  Nothing else even comes close.  The content may be questioned but the fact that we have accurate copies of what was written cannot.