# On what basis do Evangelical apologists argue that Muhammad committed sin?

Tags: history, apologetics, islam, comparative-religion

Muhammad claimed to be a Prophet of God, even God's last Prophet.  As such his life should have been godly.

There is not much of his life revealed in the Quran.  What is spoken of sometimes needs one of the reliable hadith to explain what is being talked about in the Quran. For Muhammad's life it is necessary to go to the hadith.  The most reliable hadith are gathered in the Kutub al-Sittah sometimes called the Sihah al-Sittah, which includes the Sahih Bukhari, the Sahih Muslim, the Sunan al-Sughra and the Sunan Abu Dawood.  The most reliable is considered to be the Sahih Bukhari (which is available online in English).

My question is "On what basis do Evangelical apologists argue that Muhammad committed sin?"

Comment: Are you asking "How do they convince Muslims that Muhammad committed sin?". There might be different arguments from different apologists.

Comment: Also Muslims do not necessary believe that Muhammad was without sin: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17137/%D9%90did-prophet-muhammad-sin-if-so-what-was-that

Comment: @AndrewShanks.   It will be good if there is a reference to the aforementioned Evangelical apologists.  Even so, why would a prophet needs to be sinless?  Christianity & Judaism never claim OT prophets to be sinless.

Comment: I would say it is on the basis that Jesus Christ is the only person who was ever born without the inherited curse of Adam and lived without sin.  Muhammad falls into the category of all others.  Are you inquiring about allegations of a particular manifestation of sin?

Comment: @DJClayworth - I don't really know how the question itself could be improved.... "committed _grevious_ sin"? - it may be subjective.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - Its true what you say.  David sinned, but in general he was a man after God's own heart.  I suppose I am meaning something like "..argue that Muhammad's life was characterised by sin"

Comment: Would Christian apologists argue that? Of course preaching things that are not true about God would count as grievious sin (Christians would say he did that, Muslims of course would not). But you don't have to be a massive sinner to be wrong.

Comment: 1. The OP does not substantiate the claim that apologists _do_ make such claims. 2. The OP then refers to religious documentation other than the Christian bible. 3. The OP also refers to a religious figure other than Jewish or Christian figures. 4 What exactly has this got to do with _Christianity_ ? ? ?

Comment: From what I understand about Islam, the Christian concept of sin (that every person has inherited sin from Adam, therefore all have sinned and only Jesus’ sacrifice can atone for sin) is not the same as the Muslim concept of sin. Muslim’s believe their good deeds can outweigh their bad deeds and Allah is merciful.  It might be useful to establish what Muslims believe sin is. The answers from this question might be helpful: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/215/was-the-prophet-sinless

Comment: I believe Islam can be well described as a Christian cult.  In many ways it is far closer to Christianity than the beliefs of the Mormons: there is only one God; he is the God of the Bible (and Quran); there is a Day of Judgement; there is a Heaven & a Hell; Jesus is the Word of God, the Messiah; was born of a virgin, worked miracles, will be there on the day of judgement: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77765/why-does-the-quran-mention-jesus-christ-25-times-but-mohammad-only-5-times/77774#77774 True, Moslems don't read the Bible, neither do Mormons, except to cherry pick.

Comment: The site accepts questions about Mormons, and Mormons can even contribute to the site!  The only difference is that Mormons have a pretence to call themselves Christian, and Moslems usually do not, except some Moslem apologists claim they are understanding the Bible better than Christians.

Answer (score 2):

**Question: On what basis do Evangelical apologists argue that Muhammad committed sin?**

Romans 5:12 tells us that through Adam sin entered the world, and so death was passed on to all men because “the wages of sin is death” (Romans 6:23).  King David understood his sinful nature: “Surely I was sinful at birth, sinful from the time my mother conceived me” (Psalm51:5).  Christians acknowledge that we are all natural born sinners and the Bible confirms this: “For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God” (Romans 3:23).  That would include Muhammad.  The only sinless person was Christ Jesus: “He committed no sin, and no deceit was found in his mouth” (1 Peter 2:22). That is the biblical and Christian understanding of sin – we ALL sin, and there is no exception.

The difference between the Christian understanding of sin and the Muslim understanding of sin is significant.  Christians believe that sinners have broken God’s law (1 John 3:4); sinners are slaves to sin (John 8:34); they face the judgment of God (Jude 1:14–15); they are on the road to death and destruction (Ezekiel 18:20; James 1:5). The ONLY solution to sin is to place our faith in what God, through Christ Jesus, has done – He laid down his life to pay the price of sin, then was raised from the dead and is now seated at the right hand of God.

Muslims do not believe this.  They deny that Jesus died and was resurrected.  They do not believe in original sin or that every person since Adam has inherited sin.

> In Islam, a sin is any act of disobedience against the commands of Allah, which may entail punishment in the Hereafter.  In contrast, a good deed (if done sincerely and accepted by the Almighty Allah) will entail reward in the Hereafter.  The crucial piece is that sins vs. good deeds are weighed, and the human being is judged on the difference; that determines where you end up.  Sin is not a state of being (no "Original Sin").  Sin is an action that you commit.  Sins can be committed accidentally, although you are not held accountable for them in that case.  You can think of committing sins, but you are only held accountable for actions, not thoughts. https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/351/what-is-the-muslim-definition-of-sin

Muslims believe they can atone for their own sins by good works.  If they comply with the Five Pillars of Islam and perform more good deeds than bad deeds, then Allah may be merciful and they will not go to hell.  With regard to Muhammad, I posted a question on the Islam site and received this answer:

> The theological Islamic position is that prophets can not commit sins.  What is attributed to e.g. Noah, Abraham, Moses عليه السلام etc. are not actual sins - rather excusable or lawful matters over which they repent out of their extreme piety and because of holding themselves more strictly accountable in view of their status and relationship with Allah.

> 47:19 does not mention a sin of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ and if you look at its exegesis there are various explanations on whether it is addressed to the Prophet or an ummati, and in which of their possible meanings the words غفر (forgive) and ذنب (sin) are used.

> Regarding the incidents over which the prophets repented: One is not necessarily attributed to all prophets, and Jesus عليه السلام is among those prophets regarding whom nothing of the sort is mentioned in the Quran. Although from hadith it may be construed that he is concerned over people committing shirk using him.

The following answer is in response to another question on the Islam site regarding Jesus/Isa being without sin.  This makes reference to the Hadiths (traditions):  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/215/was-the-prophet-sinless/52867#52867

I hope this will help readers to understand the theological differences that separate the Christian view of sin, repentance, forgiveness and salvation from the Muslim view.   Muslims might believe that Muhammad never sinned, but their view of sin differs from the biblical view of sin.  Only Christ Jesus was without sin.  He died so that we might live:

> For our sake he made him to be sin who knew no sin, so that in him we might become the righteousness of God (2 Corinthians 5:21).

P.S. There is a religious movement that attempts to merge Islam and Christianity.  It is known as ‘Chrislam’:

> While it is undeniable that there are many similarities between Christianity and Islam (and Judaism, for that matter), Chrislam ultimately fails because Christianity and Islam are diametrically opposed on the most important of issues – the identity of Jesus Christ. True Christianity declares Jesus to be God incarnate. For Christians, the deity of Christ is a non-negotiable, for without His deity, Jesus’ death on the cross would not have been sufficient to be the atoning sacrifice for the sins of the entire world (1 John 2:2).

> Islam adamantly rejects the deity of Christ. The Qur’an declares the idea that Jesus is God to be blasphemy (5:17). Belief in the deity of Christ is considered shirk (“polytheism”) to Muslims. Further, Islam denies the death of Christ on the cross (4:157–158). The most crucial doctrine of the Christian faith is rejected in Islam.  Source:  https://www.gotquestions.org/Chrislam.html

Comment: Thank you Lesley!