# According to LDS theology, did God create the world ex nihilo?

Tags: creation, lds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [According to the Mormon doctrines, who created the universe?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/according-to-the-mormon-doctrines-who-created-the-universe)

I was listening to a story on NPR about Mormon business ethics, when the claim was made that according to the LDS church, God did not create the world out of nothing, but rather out of chaos.  Is this understanding correct?

Along with this, I understand there is a claim that men and women can become like God as well.  How do these two relate? Is it understood that Mormons can actually speak their own universes into existence?

Comment: The short answer: yes, in a sense, it is correct. Another very similar question here would be: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-mormon-doctrine-regarding-becoming-a-god

Comment: Agreed, this is a duplicate.  I VTC my own question :)  I think this should remain as a signpost, however

Comment: Two community VTCs in addition to the OP's own VTC...may as well toss in my super-VTC. :P

Comment: @El'endiaStarman *sudo-VTC :P