# In what manner does the LDS believe we may become like God?

Tags: nature-of-god, lds, nature-of-man

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the Mormon doctrine regarding becoming a god?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-mormon-doctrine-regarding-becoming-a-god)

Lorenzo Snow, a prophet of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, stated:

> As man is, God once was; as God is, man may become.

I realize that there is a lot of deep theology bound up in that statement (some of which is detailed in this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-mormon-doctrine-regarding-becoming-a-god)), however none of the answers to that question really answered my fairly simple question in regards to the quote above.

#### In what manner may we become like God?

In all manners? Will we be omniscient, omnipotent? Since we are made in God's image, we are already in several ways "like God" (e.g. our ability to create, we have free-will, a conscience, and as the serpent tempted Eve in the garden we have become like God in our knowledge of good and evil).

Is the converse the same? (i.e. the manner in which we may become like God is the same manner that God was once like man?)

**Edit:**

As a clarification, I have the image of a worthy individual becoming a god and setting out on his own (["Go west young man!"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_West,_young_man)). What I'm wondering is, if it the more correct understanding is that we become "one in purpose" with the Godhead?

Comment: FYI, divinization is not unique to Mormanism. It's a pretty fundamental Christian belief, seemingly less emphasized in Protestantism, but not absent.

Comment: @svidgen Agreed, edited the question's title to clarify the scope.

Comment: Ah, good edit. Though, I didn't mean to suggest the question was vague. I only wanted to ensure you and other readers were aware that the concept you're asking about is not a Mormon invention.

Comment: Added some clarification to expand a bit on the subtle difference I'm trying to find an answer to.

Comment: I'm still not convinced of the difference here. It's a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that your trying to find something that's not there.

The doctrine is simple and plainly stated by the prophet just as you quoted:

> As man is, God once was; as God is, man may become.

That's it, there is nothing else to it.

If you want a scriptural reference from the New Testament:

> Romans 8:16-17, 16) The spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the children of God: 17) And if children, then heirs; heirs of God, and joint-heirs with Christ; if so be that we suffer with *him* that we may be also **glorified** together. [bold mine]

That is the basis of the entire belief for Latter-Day-Saints. We are children of our Heavenly Father and eventually we may become like Him, in ***ALL*** His glory.