# How does LDS reconcile progression to Godhood with the Genesis temptation of Adam to be like God?

Tags: lds, theological-frameworks

This [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mormon_cosmology) states:

> In Mormonism, the concept of divinity centers around an idea of
> "exaltation" and "eternal progression": **mortals themselves may become
> gods and goddesses** in the afterlife, be rulers of their own heavenly
> kingdoms, have spirit children, and increase in power and glory
> forever.

The book of Genesis describes a temptation that came to Adam from the Serpent, by way of Eve.  A forbidden fruit was eaten but the fruit was merely the vehicle for the temptation to "be like God". The temptation was to believe God was holding out on them and to make themselves like God by doing that which God had forbidden.

> But the serpent said to the woman, “You will not surely die. **For God knows that when you eat of it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God**, knowing good and evil.” So when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was a delight to the eyes, and that the tree was to be desired to make one wise, she took of its fruit and ate, and she also gave some to her husband who was with her, and he ate. Then the eyes of both were opened, and they knew that they were naked. And they sewed fig leaves together and made themselves loincloths. - Genesis 3:4-7

If the Wikipedia entry accurately represents Mormon belief, how does LDS theology reconcile this hope of progression to Godhood with the temptation that Adam succumbed to (to be like God) as recorded in the book of Genesis?

Comment: related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/49034/lds-teaching-about-man-being-able-to-become-god-and-the-snake-telling-eve-that

Comment: @coderworks The previous question to which you link was in respect of Eve (only) and the fact of an offer being made to become 'as God', knowing good and evil. This question centres on the aspect of Adam committing a trangression whereby all his progeny were brought into a state of sin under his headship (and , thus, there being no 'exaltation' at all, but rather a finality of degradation).

Comment: the LDS don't view eating the fruit as ruining humanity, so there isn't reconciliation. Without eating the fruit the rest of mankind wouldn't have come to earth, and death wouldn't have occurred so progression (for Adam/Eve and us) was in a sense paused at this point.

Comment: @depperm "Through one man sin entered the world, and death through sin".  Is "eating the fruit" a euphemism for sexual relations in a marriage?

Comment: I agree with Romans 5:12. No 'eating the fruit' is not a euphemism for sexual relations (the LDS don't teach this, nor do I believe the scriptures teach this)

Comment: @depperm It's not the first time I've seen mention of the notion that, without the Fall, Adam and Eve would not have procreated;  that they would have remained "innocent".

Comment: ok, so what is the question? See also [Fall of Adam and Eve](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/fall-of-adam-and-eve?lang=eng#title4)

Comment: I suppose this, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30144/in-mormonism-how-is-the-doctrine-of-adam-eve-inability-to-have-children-prior, answers it?

Comment: If there is something there that doesn't answer your question, update the question and I'll look at it again

Comment: Just because eating the fruit did not bring upon immortality and deification, does not mean that the latter two will not come by other means; after all, all Christians believe in immortality following the final resurrection.

Comment: @depperm I have edited the question to be more pointed (I hope).

Comment: I don't think the temptation was to believe God was holding out on them, it was to eat the forbidden fruit. If you are tempted by a cookie, it isn't necessarily that it is the best cookie, or that it is something more than not yours. I'll still work on an answer, but the wording seems strange

Comment: The fruit is not central but merely the vehicle of the prohibition.  You won't surely die (from eating it).  God knows when you eat it you will be like him.  That's the temptation.

Answer (score 5):

God confirmed that man (Genesis 3:22) "is become as one of us, to know good and evil", so this part of Satan's speech was actually not a lie.

1. Satan claimed that Adam would not surely die. This was the overt lie.
2. As the OP suggests, he maliciously insinuated that the reason for forbidding the fruit was that God was holding out and did not want Adam to become as the gods, knowing good and evil.
3. Instead, he claimed that one could become like God *by disobedience*. This was the temptation.
4. This was a lie by omission. The knowledge of good and evil alone was not sufficient to become fully like God. By disobeying, Adam became subject to the will of the devil. (D&C 29:40)
5. Satan's intent was to trap mankind whether immortal or mortal in a state of misery,  (Alma 12:26, 2 Ne 9:9), with a possible additional effect of nullifying God's decree and making him a liar (Alma 12:23)

The LDS view is that God does want his children to be become like Him, but that it must be done in His way and on His terms. Those terms include faithful obedience to his Only Begotten. They also include not claiming godlike knowledge, authority, or power before those have been granted, or in ways based on compulsion or deceit.

Comment: *The LDS view is that God does want his children to be become like Him*.  Adam and Eve were created in the image of God and lost ground from there.  Does LDS teach that they could have progressed toward Godhood from that initial creation had they not sinned?

Comment: @Mike Borden This really should be another question but as far as we understand it, no, they could not have progressed.

Comment: God wanted them to become like Him and they couldn't unless they sinned?

Comment: Mike Borden: Paradoxical, isn't it? Yes, they (and the rest of us) had to have a real choice and real experience of good and evil; to err and be forgiven, which was not possible while still in God's presence.

Comment: God never sinned.  How could Adam become like God by sinning?

Answer (score 2):

No reconciliation is needed.

Before partaking of the fruit Adam and Eve

1. were innocent (didn't know good from evil, wouldn't* have children)
2. immortal (wouldn't die, wouldn't progress)<sup>1, 2, 3</sup>

> [God] then gave [the commandment not to partake of the fruit] (the opportunity of choice) to Adam and Eve, and he also gave them their free agency (the freedom of choice). Then, and this is a very important point, he did not hold Adam and Eve responsible for any transgression they committed in their state of innocence.

> God knew before the earth was ever created that it would be necessary for Adam and Eve to fall so they “would have seed.” Thus, even before the earth was created, Jesus Christ had agreed that he would pay the penalty required by the law of justice for the transgression of the law that resulted in the fall of Adam and Eve.<sup>2</sup>

President Joseph Fielding Smith said:

> Let’s thank the Lord, when we pray, for Adam. If it hadn’t been for Adam, I wouldn’t be here; you wouldn’t be here; we would be waiting in the heavens as spirits. …

> We are in the mortal life to get an experience, a training, that we couldn’t get any other way. And in order to become gods, it is necessary for us to know something about pain, about sickness, and about the other things that we partake of in this school of mortality.

> So don’t let us, brethren and sisters, complain about Adam and wish he hadn’t done something that he did. I want to thank him. I am glad to have the privilege of being here and going through mortality, and if I will be true and faithful to the covenants and obligations that are upon me as a member of the Church and in the kingdom of God, I may have the privilege of coming back into the presence of the Eternal Father; and that will come to you as it will to me, sons and daughters of God, entitled to the fullness of celestial glory.<sup>3</sup>

The Fall was necessary for progression to begin/be possible.

<sub>1 [Genesis 2:17, 25](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/gen/2.17,25?lang=eng#p17?lang=eng), [2 Nephi 2:22-23](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/2.22-23?lang=eng#p22?lang=eng)</sub>

<sub>2 [Why did the Lord command Adam and Eve to multiply in the Garden of Eden when they could not have children before the fall?](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/new-era/1973/09/q-and-a-questions-and-answers/why-did-the-lord-command-adam-and-eve-to-multiply-in-the-garden-of-eden-when-they-could-not-have-children-before-the-fall?lang=eng)</sub>

<sub>3 [Genesis 3 The Fall](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/old-testament-student-manual-genesis-2-samuel/genesis-3-the-fall?lang=eng)</sub>

<sub>* **not couldn't, they had the ability**</sub>

Comment: Is the answer, then, that LDS doesn't believe the actual temptation was to "be like God" as recorded in Genesis?

Comment: Regarding footnote link #2 *But if there is no possibility for sin and for the punishment and misery that accompany it, then there is no possibility for good and for the blessings and joy that follow* - When God finished creation He declared it to be very good thus demonstrating that good does not need sin, punishment, and misery to exist.  The ground was cursed for Adam's sake: Having grasped at Godhood, a life of ease wouldn't have taught him his error.

Comment: @MikeBorden No we do, eating of the fruit did let them be like God by knowing between good and evil. A few explanations on your second question. I believe the use of good is different (I can make 2 cakes and one be very good without the other being sinful/evil) 1) God created all things and the earth creation was very good. *retracted last statement, I believe the use of the word is different*

Comment: @MikeBorden Essentially, Men is supposed to become righteous, meaning choosing good over evil. This is impossible if Men does not know Good from Evil. It's not enough to just not do evil.

Comment: @kutschkem Before Adam and Eve internalized the desire to be like God in discerning good from evil (usurping God's prerogative) they were not neutral.  They took their direction from God and, therefore, they did good.  They were righteous.  When they decided to discern and decide for themselves they ceased doing good because they stopped relying upon God's discernment.  Being merely created beings they aspired to Godhood...and died.

Comment: @MikeBorden If I understand what you are saying I don't think the LDS believe the same thing. Adam and Eve without knowledge of right and wrong couldn't sin and so they also weren't righteous/good (they weren't evil) they were 'neutral' See 2 Nephi 2:11. They had agency, and after making the choice and partaking of the fruit, sin was brought into the world and they could begin to be righteous/unrighteous by following/disobeying God

Comment: Think of a child. If you tell them to do something, they don't understand what they are doing, and they do that thing, it doesn't make them good/bad because they don't have knowledge of what they are doing. You can be considered good, for having them do something good but until they gain a knowledge they can be considered 'neutral'

Comment: What if you tell them to do something and they say "no!".  When you tell them to do something good and they do that thing you are teaching them to be good.  When you relay a prohibition you are likewise teaching good.  Adam was learning to be good every time He obeyed a command from God, who is good.  A newborn might be experientially neutral but is never morally neutral.

Comment: @MikeBorden everyone has agency. They again do not necessarily know what they are responding to

Comment: Every parent spends an inordinate amount of time teaching their child how to be good (through both praise and correction) and virtually no time teaching them how to be bad.  This is not because they are neutral but because they have a degraded disposition to start with and this is what Adam internalized and passed on to us:  we will determine good and evil for ourselves.