# LDS expected future relationship with God after exaltation

Tags: lds

The LDS concept of exaltation states that

> As man is, God once was; as God is, man may become.

(A quote by the LDS Prophet Lorenzo Snow, from [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12146/in-what-manner-does-the-lds-believe-we-may-become-like-god))

The question I wanted to ask is, do Mormons have an expectation on how their relationship with God will be after they have been exalted?

More specifically, if they will become equal to God in glory, is the expectation that they will at that point cease to worship God?

(From a selfish technical point of view there certainly would not seem to be any need to worship God after that point as the reward will have been received, assuming that it cannot somehow be revoked.)

Comment: There is no official doctrine in regards to this. Many things are not known unto us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just my personal belief (as an active LDS member), but I would imagine that the relationship would be similar to father-and-child.  The distance would probably be much shorter and probably seem more familial.

Will we stop worshiping Him because we are now "equal in glory"?  I don't think so, though I imagine the *method* of worship might change.  It's worth knowing that simply reaching the highest heaven (the Celestial Kingdom) doesn't automatically turn a Mormon into a God.  There is still a learning and growing process that may take thousands (if not millions) of human years!  (When you have an eternity to do it, though, it doesn't seem so bad).  Our Heavenly Father will still have plenty to teach and instruct, even in the after-life.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing.  If you'd like to strengthen your answer, I'd recommend adding sources to show that this analysis is reflective of the LDS generally.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Answer (score 1):

This answer maybe unconventional but the question is not specifically addressed that I am aware of anywhere.  I thought about it and I think I have an answer that isn't total conjecture or opinion.

Some thoughts that are just opinion though:

- Somethings like this in the afterlife cannot be fully understood simply because we aren't in the physical or spiritual state that we will be in after this life
- A loose metaphor would be that a child experiences life at different stages differently with a parent
- The former stated we can expect that the relationship with God the Father (and indeed all our family and friends that are with us) to be richer and fulfilling

With that stated I want to move on the the topic of **Honor**. The Old and New Testaments as well as the Book of Mormon, the Doctrine and Covenants and the Pearl of Great Price (the LDS Standard Works or Canon) all speak on honor and they all **Command** us to honor our father and our mother. Exodus 20:12:

> 12 ¶ Honour thy father and thy mother: that thy days may be long upon
>   the land which the Lord thy God giveth thee.

What exactly does it mean to honor someone? There are several possible connotations but I would ask that you consider the following: We not only honor our parents by obeying them but also through the respect we show them and the praise we bestow them with.  Honoring is a form of worshiping.

In LDS theology we believe in a premortal existence.  Where we existed as spirit children in our First Estate.  As his children he has bestowed upon us the gift of Agency.  The ability to make choices for ourselves.  At some point there was a Grand Council in which our Father presented to us the opportunity to continue on the our Second Estate.  This next step in progressing to be more like our Father required us to receive our physical bodies and to come to Earth to be tested.  We must prove that we can follow God's commands while separated from him and with the temptations of a physical form.  We would pass through a veil of forgetfulness. We would commit wrong doings - sins, and by so doing we would be cut off spiritually from God.  This spiritual death would require a Savior, a perfect, blameless sacrifice.  Jehovah volunteered.  At this time however Lucifer stepped forward with a different plan.  His plan was coercion so that no one was lost and all would return to Father.  He felt that his plan (which removed our Agency) was superior and as such he demanded Father's **HONOR** and thus his **GLORY**. Found in the Pearl of Great Price, in the book of Moses (Moses 4:1-4)

> 1 And I, the Lord God, spake unto Moses, saying: That Satan, whom thou
>   hast commanded in the name of mine Only Begotten, is the same which
>   was from the beginning, and he came before me, saying—Behold, here am
>   I, send me, I will be thy son, and I will redeem all mankind, that one
>   soul shall not be lost, and surely I will do it; wherefore give me
>   thine honor.
>
> 2 But, behold, my Beloved Son, which was my Beloved and Chosen from
>   the beginning, said unto me—Father, thy will be done, and the glory be
>   thine forever.
>
> 3 Wherefore, because that Satan rebelled against me, and sought to
>   destroy the agency of man, which I, the Lord God, had given him, and
>   also, that I should give unto him mine own power; by the power of mine
>   Only Begotten, I caused that he should be cast down;
>
> 4 And he became Satan, yea, even the devil, the father of all lies, to
>   deceive and to blind men, and to lead them captive at his will, even
>   as many as would not hearken unto my voice.

Satan wanted his honor, his glory, his power, his throne.  He rebelled and several of the spirit children of God followed him.  The didn't keep the First Estate and thus never received their physical bodies.  They refuse to honor Father (ie praise, give glory, or worship).

We keep the Second Estate by continuing to show him honor, we learn best by example and so we are placed in families which are smaller and imperfect but still models of the grander and greater spiritual family that we belong to (this is why we call each other Brother and Sister in the LDS faith). So God commands us to show our parents honor.  We honor God through worship and by following his commands.  If we complete this Second Estate by following God through his Son Jesus Christ we can inherit his Kingdom.

This is a long winded round about way to say that I believe that we will still give honor, glory, praise and thus worship to God even as we approach him in knowledge and glory.  This is because he will always be our Father and his Son will always be our Savior.  Without either one we are nothing.  Will the manner of worship change?  I hope so, because the manner in which we worship even in this life changes as we progress. Much like children when they are more self sufficient no longer need their parents still can show honor to their parents (at least good children do this).  The manner of the relationship changes and the ways we honor our parents changes but if we are good children we still bestow them with praise, respect and honor.