# How do Mormons understand Revelation 22:3?

Tags: nature-of-god, lds, trinity, revelation

[Revelation 22:3](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rev/22) in the King James Version:

> 3 And there shall be no more curse: but the throne of God and of the Lamb shall be in it; and his servants shall serve him:

To me this appears to indicate Jesus and God are one, and not separate beings, for the sake of the same throne and the singular pronouns his and him. How do Mormons understand this verse?

Comment: I have edited your question to be a little better formatted, and to read a bit better, and I removed your second, unrelated, question about planets. If you want to ask another question about planets, feel free to do that, but it should be its own post.

Comment: why did anyone feel the need to take down the NIV and put up King James?  and also feel the need to insert part A?  The NIV has a period and not a colon also. Not that i would think it changes the import. The edits are quite disconcerting

Comment: @NervousNelly Welcome to Stack Exchange, where nearly anyone can edit anyone else's posts. Asking for an LDS interpretation of the NIV doesn't make any sense because the LDS don't read the NIV. I added a link to the full passage so readers can obtain the context of the verse, which is important.

Comment: the verse context is not illuminated at all by the addition. in fact it would only make someone want to research what curse and thus confuse the narrow issue

Comment: And don't ask that other question, it's [already been asked and answered](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/15581/1003).

Comment: is this a hostile work environment?

Comment: @NervousNelly The LDS are basically KJV only. Matt's edit is intended to get you a good LDS answer to your question.

Comment: (I know- they believe in the special inspiration of that translation which is a different thing, but it isn't far off the mark to say KJV only)

Comment: "but the throne of God and of the Lamb shall be in it" - you may think that it means that God and the Son are one.  I do not believe this makes a very clear statement - and I am not Mormon.  In your question, your statement is "appears to indicate" - which alludes to some form of interpretation.

Comment: everything in the world is interpreted The Freemason

Comment: I do not disagree.  However there are items which people would interpret similarly - this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 5):

> Revelation 3:21 To him that overcometh will I grant to sit with me in my throne, even as I also overcame, and am set down **with** my Father in his throne.

This verse shows that the throne belongs to Jesus Christ along with his father. We interpret it through this verse. Kind of a short answer but it gets the point accross.

Answer (score 1):

> 3 And there shall be no more curse: but the throne of God and of the Lamb shall be in it; and his servants shall serve him:

It's quite simple. The "throne" (power and glory) is that of Jesus Christ and God the Father.

Christ received all that the Father had, including his power and glory. And not only did Christ receive this, but the redeemed will receive this as well.

> And if children, then heirs; **heirs of God, and joint-heirs with Christ;** if so be that we suffer with him, that we may be also glorified together.
>
> Romans 8:17
>
> To him that overcometh will I grant to **sit with me in my throne,** even as I also overcame, and **am set down with my Father in his throne.**
>
> Revelation 3:21

---

If anything, this verse seems to imply that the Father and Son are separate.

If I said, "Would you like to go to the movies with my sister and Lisa?", most people would think Lisa and my sister are different people.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, if I threw in "me" to the sentence, and the hearer accepted, there would indeed be 4 people. Imperfect phrasing, but hopefully the point is clear :)