# What was God the Father like, when he was a man?

Tags: nature-of-god, lds

According to the LDS doctrine of exaltation, God the Father was born and lived and died, and then was exhalted to Godhood by his God, in the same way that Jesus was exalted by the Father.

Is there any passage in the Mormon Scriptures or writing by Mormon teachers that discusses the life and character of the Father before he was exalted?

Comment: There is speculation that, as a man,  God the Father was the saviour of his world, just as Christ was the saviour of ours: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/38818/was-elohim-the-saviour-and-redeemer-of-his-world

Answer (score 7):

No, and in fact it is explicitly stated in LDS scriptures that such a revelation does not pertain to us:

> [Moses 1: 35](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.35?lang=eng#34)
>
> But only an account of this earth, and the inhabitants thereof,
>   give I unto you. For behold, there are many worlds that have passed
>   away by the word of my power. And there are many that now stand, and
>   innumerable are they unto man; but all things are numbered unto me,
>   for they are mine and I know them.

Any history of beings from other worlds and their experiences in mortality falls outside the scope of "only an account of this earth and the inhabitants thereof."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do first person pronouns in this passage refer to the Father?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes.  This is clear from previous verses, such as verse 33: "And worlds without number have I created; and I also created them for mine own purpose; and by the Son I created them, which is mine Only Begotten."

Comment: I agree that it's clear, I just meant to confirm. A follow-up question: are the worlds in this verse meant to mean "Earths", as in other planets, or "Cosmos" as in other creations?

Comment: @Andrew As far as I know, this distinction is never elaborated on.