# Since Mormons believe in multiple earth-like planets, do they believe that the "fall" was likewise needed on each of them?

Tags: life-of-jesus, lds, eschatology, adam-and-eve

As is brought out in the top-rated answer to [this other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/does-the-mormon-doctrine-of-exaltation-implicitly-require-acknowledging-the-exis), according to Mormon belief there are other inhabited worlds (presumably in our own universe) created by God.

The answer refers to the Book of Moses, chapter 1, where [verses 29-34](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.29-34?lang=eng) state:

> **29** And he beheld many lands; and each land was called earth, and there were inhabitants on the face thereof.**30** And it came to pass
>   that Moses called upon God, saying: Tell me, I pray thee, why these
>   things are so, and by what thou madest them? **31** And behold, the
>   glory of the Lord was upon Moses, so that Moses stood in the presence
>   of God, and talked with him face to face. And the Lord God said unto
>   Moses: For mine own purpose have I made these things. Here is wisdom
>   and it remaineth in me. **32** And by the word of my power, have I
>   created them, which is mine Only Begotten Son, who is full of grace
>   and truth. **33** And worlds without number have I created; and I also
>   created them for mine own purpose; and by the Son I created them,
>   which is mine Only Begotten. **34** And the first man of all men have
>   I called Adam, which is many.

And according to the answer to [this other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30144/in-mormonism-how-is-the-doctrine-of-adam-eve-inability-to-have-children-prior), Mormons believe that Adam and Eve were unable to have children until they ate from the tree that they were told not to eat from. The section under "Additional Notes" states:

> It is worth noting that rather than viewing the Fall of Adam and Eve
>   as an unfortunate and evil accident, one which if it had not happened,
>   everything would be perfect, Mormons see the Fall as necessary to the
>   purpose of life on earth.
>
> Life is an opportunity to learn to choose good over evil. This could
>   not happen if there was not good or evil. (See 2 Nephi 2.)
>
> The sacrifice of the Son of God was planned from "the foundation of
>   the world" (Revelation 13:8). So also was the Fall -- which
>   necessitated the sacrifice -- known from the beginning. Mormons often
>   describe the Fall as a fall downward, but also forward.

What I would like to ask is, do Mormons believe that the fall was likewise needed on each inhabited planet? And if so, do they believe that Jesus also eventually died on behalf of the inhabitants of each planet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do Mormons believe that the fall was likewise needed on each inhabited planet?

No authoritative LDS doctrine on this subject, except that the first man and woman on other worlds had the name Adam and Eve.

Moses [1:33-34](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.33-35?lang=eng#32),[4:26](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/4.26?lang=eng#25)

> 33 And worlds without number have I created; and I also created them for mine own purpose; and by the Son I created them, which is mine Only Begotten.
>
> 34 And the **first man of all men have I called Adam, which is many**.
>
> 26 And Adam called his wife’s name Eve, because she was the mother of all living; for thus have I, the Lord God, called the **first of all women, which are many.**
>
> Do they believe that Jesus also eventually died on behalf of the inhabitants of each planet?

Mormons believe that Jesus only needed to perform the Atonement once because it was an infinite and eternal sacrifice.

[Doctrine and Covenants 76:22-24,40-43](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.22-24%2C40-43?lang=eng#21)

> 22 And now, after the many testimonies which have been given of him, this is the testimony, last of all, which we give of him: That he lives!
>
> 23 For we saw him, even on the right hand of God; and we heard the voice bearing record that he is the Only Begotten of the Father—
>
> 24 **That by him, and through him, and of him, the worlds are and were created, and the inhabitants thereof are begotten sons and daughters unto God**.
>
> 40 And this is the gospel, the glad tidings, which the voice out of the heavens bore record unto us—
>
> 41 That he came into the world, even Jesus, to be crucified for the world, and to bear the sins of the world, and to sanctify the world, and to cleanse it from all unrighteousness;
>
> 42 **That through him all might be saved whom the Father had put into his power and made by him;**
>
> 43 **Who glorifies the Father, and saves all the works of his hands**, except those sons of perdition who deny the Son after the Father has revealed him.

In [Times and Seasons 4 no. 6](http://www.centerplace.org/history/ts/v4n06.htm) WW Phelps in a poem verse based on section 76 wrote:

> **By him, of him, and through him, the worlds were all made**,
>
> Even all that career in the heavens so broad.
>
> 20. **Whose inhabitants, too, from the first to the last**,
>
> **Are sav'd by the very same Saviour (Savior) of ours**;
>
> And, of course, are begotten God's daughters and sons,
>
> By the very same truths, and the very same pow'rs.

On why the Atonement happened here and not another world Joseph Fielding Smith speculated: ([Signs of the Times](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002O1DBHW)(this is just a link to amazon) p 5 or 12)

> Perhaps this is the reason Jesus Christ was sent here instead of some other world, for in some other world they would not have crucified Him, and His presence was needed here because of the extreme wickedness of the inhabitants of this earth

Brigham Young in [Journal of Discourses](http://jod.mrm.org/10/170) seems to agree that this world is one of the more wicked worlds.

> I suppose that God never organized an earth and peopled it that was ever reduced to a lower state of darkness, sin and ignorance than this. I suppose this is one of the lowest kingdoms that ever the Lord Almighty created, and on that account is capable of becoming exalted to be one of the highest kingdoms that has ever had an exaltation in all the eternities

See also [Alma 34:9-10,12-13](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/alma/34.9-10%2C12-13?lang=eng#8)

---

However Brigham Young taught that each world had its own Adam and Eve, and its own savior, however, please note that this is not considered final or authoritative.

> Let me open the eyes of your understanding. There has never been a time when the creations of worlds commenced. They are from eternity to eternity in their creations and redemption. After they are organized they experience the good and the evil, the light and the dark, the bitter and the sweet as you and I do. There never was a time when there were not worlds in existence as this world is, and they pass through similar changes in abiding their creation preparatory to exaltation. Worlds have always been in progress, and eternally will be.
>
> **Every world has had an Adam and an Eve, named so simply because the first man is always called Adam and the first woman, Eve. And the oldest son has always had the privilege of being ordained, appointed and called to be the heir of the family if he does not rebel against the Father, and he is the Savior of the family**. Every world that has been created has been created upon the same principle. They may vary in their varieties, yet the eternity is one: it is one eternal round.

<sub>emphasis added by me</sub>

Comment: Interesting. I do see that you wrote that Brigham Young's teachings about each world having its own Adam and Eve and savior "is not considered final or authoritative." Are any of his viewpoints in Journal of Discourses considered inspired or "canon"?

Comment: @x457812 The Journal of Discourses is not canon. It's used as an historical reference, but the doctrine within it isn't necessarily transcribed correctly. It can give us insight, but often enough insights from prophets and apostles even is opinion or speculation. Brigham Young probably speculated on things a little more than a lot of other people...

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with paradoxes.  Let's start with Moses 1:35:

> For behold, there are many worlds that have passed away by the word of my power.

There are worlds/plans that have reached their conclusion already.  Could our Jesus have been the savior for worlds that have already reached their conclusion?  If so, why must the people of our world have waited for His resurrection before they could be resurrected?  Paradox.  Let's look at Moses 1:32.

> And by the word of my power, have I created them, which is mine Only Begotten Son, who is full of grace and truth.

We're tempted to think that Jesus was the one and only "only begotten" son of God.  That would mandate that He was the savior for plans past and completed.  However, Moses 1:33-34.

> And worlds without number have I created; and I also created them for mine own purpose; and by the Son I created them, which is mine Only Begotten. And the first man of all men have I called Adam, which is many.

OK, so the first man is named Adam, regardless of who the actual person is.  That suggests that "Savior" is a role that could have been played by others.  Let's look a bit earlier in the story.  Moses 1:19.

> Satan cried with a loud voice, and ranted upon the earth, and commanded, saying: I am the Only Begotten, worship me.

Satan tried to claim the title.  He wanted the title since the Council in Heaven ("Here am I, send me..." [Abr 3:27](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/abr/3.27?lang=eng&clang=eng#p26).

So, different people play the roles of Adam, Eve, and Savior.  This makes sense as we believe...

> All truth is independent in that sphere in which God has placed it, to act for itself, as all intelligence also; otherwise there is no existence. ([D&C 93:30](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/93.30?lang=eng#p29))

In other words (and to apply this verse to our discussion), what's true for us (e.g., who plays the role of Adam, Eve, Savior, etc.) is not necessarily true for other plans.  Why is this important to answer the OP's question?

Because of a snippet we learn from the LDS Endowment ceremony.  Lucifer is asked what he's doing in the Garden.  His answer?  "That which has been done on other worlds."

At this point in time, Lucifer doesn't know that our Father and Jesus had planed for his role as Satan on our earth ([Moses 4:6](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/4.6?lang=eng#p5)).  He was still acting (per his claim that he was the Only Begotten) as if he could take control and be the savior of this plan.  From this perspective, his answer (and his reaction to his subsequent judgment) makes perfect sense: the process of kickstarting the plan as he had done had been used elsewhere and he was right for it to start this way here.

Except he was punished for doing so.  This plan is *a little different* than other plans.

The truth is that we, as a Church, do not know what has transpired in other plans.  We have tantalizing little bits that suggest both similarities and differences.  did someone have to fall in another plan?  We simply don't know.  Could they have succeeded in their plan without falling?  We simply don't know that, either.  All we do know is that at least two previous plans were kickstarted by giving Adam and Eve the knowledge of good and evil (I'm sure they could have sinned all by themselves thereafter, if a Fall was required) — and that on this one that was not to be the case.  Rather, Adam and Eve were commanded not to eat of the fruit, and Lucifer was allowed to tempt them, bringing about the Fall.

Comment: Just pointing out that the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints considers knowledge from the Endowment ceremony, and other ceremonies reserved for the temples, to be most sacred, and does not discuss outside of the temples.  All are invited to prepare themselves and to be instructed further on these topics in the Lord's holy house.
https://www.lds.org/manual/preparing-to-enter-the-holy-temple/preparing-to-enter-the-holy-temple?lang=eng

Comment: @gscoulson, I appreciate your concern, but I believe you missed the point of the relevant paragraph.  Taken at its word, you cannot discuss outside of a temple anything about baptisms, confirmations, or ordination to the priesthood, because they are also temple ordinances (you used the phrase "reserved for the temples."  It isn't used in the manual.).  Take a moment to review 1 Peter 3:15 and Matt 7:6 and consider how to balance those two statements with this question.  You may even want to post an answer of your own.