# Do any denominations object to writing/ saying "the god" instead of "God"?

Tags: translation

For example, the King James Version translates Gen. 1:1 as,

> In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.

If I translate it as,

> In the beginning, the god created the heavens and the earth.

Would any denomination object to that translation?

Comment: Many 2nd-language English speakers do this - I assume you mean as an intentional decision?

Comment: It would be an intentional choice, sure.

Comment: Should I ask a seperate question about the use of capitals for 'He'/he', 'His/his' in different editions of the Bible or can that be included in the question?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you asking? Is there a specific doubt you're trying to address? Or simply idle curiosity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No denomination I know of would *not* object to that text. The reason being that using "God" refers specifically to the god of Israel and Christians, whereas "the god" refers to *some* god creating the heavens and the earth, meaning that "the god" only gains meaning from context. Should this excerpt be taken without its reference (Genesis 1:1) and its reader not knowing it was from the Bible, it would look like it was simply referring to *a* god, not *the* God.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Nice first post!  Don't take this next as a commentary on the quality of your answer, it's just standard to invite new visitors to check out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: From what I've learned from [participating on this site](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/82/was-jesus-a-separate-god), it appears that Jehovah's Witnesses would take that as a good translation.  I think they start John's Gospel with "a god"

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that denominations would actually object to that as a theological point so much as a linguistic point. אֱלֹהִים translates to "God" or "Divine beings" (yes, the word can be plural). And while  ὁ  θεὸς , on the other hand (the words used in Acts 3:13 to say, "the God of Abraham") translate to *the God*, in the Hebrew they are rendered as אֱ"הֵ י, which also does not have a definite article.

As to use of "the God", it is syntactically awkward in English unless contextualized (so "the God of Abraham" is fine). This is especially true since "God", in a monotheistic construct (the dominant concept in western nations), functions as much as a name as it does a title or description. While it is not syntactically incorrect to say, "the Barak Obama"*, people will look at you strangely. And this has much to do with the way the Hebrew was structured. For example, Psalm 90:2 has the line "Thou Art God". When I cross checked German, Italian, and French translations I found that there was no definite article there.

---

<sup>* Not saying that he should be equated to God, but he was the first person I thought of when I thought, "who is someone that everyone will know?"</sup>

Comment: Excellent, I answered theological objections and you answered linguistic, we're covered regardless of which version he was looking for!

Comment: Although "I'm not sure that denominations would actually object to that as a theological point" is a misled statement,as I pointed out its problems from a theological standpoint