# Why is God three persons rather than four or more?

Tags: trinity

This question is about the Holy Trinity. Did the Scriptures explained that God is necessarily three persons?

[ This question doesn't challenge the Trinity if it is true but rather, the question, if answered will be for the benefit of the Trinitarian]

Comment: It is known that some Christian sects reject Trinitarianism altogether, because they may believe that there is not enough biblical evidence to suggest that God is three. I think the fact that scripture does not really suggest Trinitarianism explicitly is the prime reason why people disagree with each other. So, it may be difficult for people on both sides (Trinitarian and non-Trinitarian) to support their points, and therefore, it's largely opinion.

Comment: Good news, someone already answered this at  [Why is the Trinity a Trinity?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8943/why-is-the-trinity-a-trinity), so you don't need to wait for an answer!