# What are the differences between "spiration" and "procession"?

Tags: trinity, word-study, persons-of-the-trinity

According to Merriam-Webster Dictionary, ***[proceed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceed)*** means:

> Full Definition of proceed; intransitive **verb**
>
> 1:  **to come forth from a source** :  issue
>
> 2
>   a:  to continue after a pause or interruption
>   b:  to go on in an orderly regulated way
>
> 3
>   a:  **to begin and carry on an action, process, or movement**
>   b:  to be in the process of being accomplished; the work is proceeding well
>
> 4:  **to move along a course**

***[Spiration](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spiration)*** means:

> b (1):  **the act by** or manner in **which the Holy Spirit proceeds** from the Father or from the Father and the Son (2):  the relation subsisting by virtue of this procession

***[Procession](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procession)*** means:

> a:  **continuous forward movement**:  progression
>   b:  emanation; the Holy Spirit's procession from the Father

The Nicene Creed says God proceeds (verb) from God and God.

The noun spiration is the *act* of this proceeding.

Sort of like how the noun "hearing" is "the act of perceiving sounds" to describe the verb "hear".

The noun *procession* means "continuous motion forward".

So procession is the *act* of proceeding.

What are the differences between spiration and procession so that we could understand them as two distinct *acts*?

Comment: It's the same difference as between "to be loved" and "to love."

Comment: @Geremia So it means "the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and Son" and "the Father and Son proceed the Holy Spirit"?

Comment: No, that's different. Procession of the Holy Spirit from the Father and Son is a different relation than what the Holy Spirit has to the Father and the Son. Think about human relationships: My relationship to my father is clearly not my father's relationship to me.

Comment: @Geremia What I mean is, couldn't Aquinas just as easily said "The answer to what it means for the Holy Spirit to proceed from the Father and Son is this: just as the Son *is begotten of* the Father, and the Father *begets* the Son; likewise the Holy Spirit *proceeds from* the Father and Son, and the Father and Son *proceed* the Holy Spirit."? Is that all this really means?

Comment: Yes, provided it's understood that the two processions are distinct.

Comment: For more info, these books are good: basic intro: [_The Trinity_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5712) by Trinity expert [Fr. Emery, O.P.](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/matches/authors/478); more advanced treatments: Fr. Emery's [_The Trinitarian Theology of St. Thomas Aquinas_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/matches/authors/4304), Fr. Pohle's [_The Divine Trinity_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/matches/authors/3784), and Fr. Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.'s [_The Trinity and God the Creator_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/matches/authors/3085).

Comment: The Holy Trinity is the greatest mystery of the faith that God had to reveal to us (since [it cannot be known by philosophical arguments](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50205/1787)). The manifestation of the Trinitarian life of God is the reason Christ took on human nature. Check out those books for a systematic treatment of the Trinity (what Persons are, what procession means, what the relations in the Trinity are, how they relate to the Persons and God's essence, etc.).

Comment: Since God is one, all these terms can easily be confused in the minds of those beginning to understand the Trinity, but St. Thomas et al. make distinctions that really elucidate the differences and relations between what the terms signify, so a systematic study is indispensable. St. Thomas and his commentators even present the various terms in the proper order conducive to understanding in the learner (processions, relations, then Persons, etc.).