# How is the doctrine of the trinity substantiated?

Tags: trinity

In an [answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/49936/38106) it was said that Jesus never says he is God or 'God the Son' as part of a trinity (reformatted):

> He has a God - the same (creator) God as all humans.
>
> - John 5:44 -- *the one and only God*
> - 2 Cor 1:3, Eph 1:3, Col 1:3, 2 Cor 11:31, Rom 15:6, Rom 1:7 -- *the God of our Lord Jesus*
> - 1 Pet 1:3 Heb 1:8-9 -- *God anointed Jesus*
> - Rev: 1:1, 1:6, 3:12 -- *even ascended, Jesus still has the same God of him and of us*
>
> Jesus often refers to his Father and God in an equivalent manner:
>
> - "You have loved me and have believed that I came from God. I came from the Father and have come into the world." (John 16:27)
> - I am ascending to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God. (John 20:17)
> - a man who has told you the truth that I heard from God. (John 8:40)

This got me thinking: **What *is* the logical argumentation for the doctrine of trinity?**

It does not seem to be directly stated in the bible as a doctrine, although it *seems* - in a way - kind of obvious to me when reading, e.g. the gospel of John in one go. However, "seems obvious" is hardly a good argument.

Comment: "What is the logical argumentation for the doctrine of trinity?" seems to be a duplicate of: "[Philosophical proofs that God must be triune?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50202/1787)" or "[Have any Christian thinkers expressed the idea that the Trinity can be proven independently from Scripture?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/42235/1787)" (cf. "[What is the meaning of 'is' in the context of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/53289/1787)")