# Is the concept of God in Christianity (the Trinity) three Gods or One?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity

I don't understand the concept of God in Christianity. Based on what I do know, there is God, the Son of God and the Holy Spirit -- doesn't this add up to 3 Gods?

In Christianity, is there there One (True God) or are there three gods? If there are three gods, what is the role of each one? And who was the original God? Who is the father to the "Son of God"?

Comment: related - [What is the biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/72/69)

Comment: Christianity is definitely Mono Theistic.

Comment: This question should be closed as primarily opinion-based. It does not specify any denomination or tradition. This means that answers from any Christian perspective should be allowable. However, my answer from a non-Trinitarian perspective was deleted as "not an answer." This demonstrates that the question is being judged from a "truth" perspective rather than from a "what do Christians believe" perspective. In other words, as asked, the question and its handling is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden The Trinity is three in one. That's the traditional usage of the word. Post your answer in chat so I can see it. Or maybe in meta.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden I don't agree. If a question asks, "What does X doctrine mean?" it's pretty clearly asking for the perspective of those who believe X doctrine. In this case, X is the trinity. "Do trinitarians believe that they believe in three gods or one?" is the actual question, but wording it that way would be unnecessarily cumbersome. I don't see a real problem with this question.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude But the question is not asking, "What do trinitarians believe?" It's asking, "Is the Trinity one God or three Gods?" That's a truth question, which means it is primarily opinion-based. It could be *edited* to be a non-truth-based and non-opinion-based question. But as the question stands now, it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @fredsbend I'll do one better. I've asked a new question, and re-posted my answer there: [Why do some Christian groups view the most common concept of God in Christianity (the Trinity) as a belief three gods rather than in one God?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42211/why-do-some-christian-groups-view-the-most-common-concept-of-god-in-christianity/42212#42212) To see the answer as originally posted here, look at the original version in the edit history.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden It's asking about the _definition_ of the trinity. Those who _believe_ a doctrine are the ones who _define_ it.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I understand that that's your interpretation of the question. And it's a reasonable interpretation to try to make the question fit into current Christianity.SE guidelines. But the fact is that the question itself does not say that it's asking for the definition of the Trinity, nor does it specify that it is asking the question of those who believe in trinitarianism. It asks a general question about whether the Trinity is three Gods or one. Under the current site rules, such a question can be answered from the perspective of *any* Christian group or denomination.

Comment: Closing as too broad, as there are multiple views on the nature of the Trinity within Christianity.  See  [Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/)

Comment: @David But there aren't any views of the trinity which say that it means three gods, are there? That's the whole definition of the word.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, there are. I provided an answer that was a Christian viewpoint that holds that the Trinity as defined in mainstream Christianity means three gods. That answer  was deleted, even though it actually was responsive to the question as asked, whereas answers that were given from a traditional Trinitarian perspective were not deleted, even though they are no more responsive to the *actual question asked* than my question was. Really, either all answers should be deleted or mine should be restored.

Comment: For those who wish to see it, my answer to this question has now been posted as a self-answered question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/42212/20394). I continue to think it is just as valid an answer to the actual question asked as all the others, and that it should not have been deleted.

Answer (score 16):

Firstly, the Trinity is not Tritheism. This is the classic argument of the Muslim against Christianity, but it is not valid. It is not valid, because the formulation of the Trinity specifically states that God is one being who exists in three persons.

The [Athansian Creed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasian_Creed) (a very ancient creed dating to the fourth or fifth century predating the Orthodox / Catholic / Protestant schims and accepted by at least [97% of all Christians](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/888/1039)) in particular states:

> we worship one God in Trinity, and Trinity in Unity; Neither confounding the Persons; nor dividing the Essence. For there is one Person of the Father; another of the Son; and another of the Holy Ghost. But the Godhead of the Father, of the Son, and of the Holy Ghost, is all one; the Glory equal, the Majesty coeternal.

The problem is not in the formulation, but rather in attempts to make an analogy to explain it. [There are great light-hearted attempts at analogy, but each suffers from a defect of some kind.](http://youtu.be/KQLfgaUoQCw) No analogy is possible, because there is no terrestrial equivalent that properly holds the tension of the fact that three people with distinct energies, capable of perfectly relating to each other, are thus so close as to be One being. Every Trinitarian heresy comes out of an attempt to force such an analogy.

- **Tritheism** in particular was endemic to those areas of Christianity that are now under Muslim control. Tritheism emphasizes the distinct personalities to the detriment of their unity. The Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are indeed so close as to be one, in the same way a Muslim would agree that a man and wife are one flesh. Sometimes the analogy of the egg (shell, yolk, and white) is used to describe this relationship, but really it doesn't convey the simultaneous distinction and sameness of personality.
- **Modalism**, on the other hand, makes the opposite mistake. It says that the Three manifestations of God are just different aspects of the same entity. (For example, some will say water is ice, fluid, and steam, or a man is father and husband)  That, however, precludes the ability of, say, God the Father to exalt God the Son (Phillipians 2:9).

That being said, the primary means of differentiating the three persons of the Trinity is by their observed actions in history:

1. God the Father is the primary actor in the history of Israel and the Old Testament. He is identified by his love, jealousy, and protection of his people. For his own glory, he rescued his people from Egypt, and showed himself powerful on behalf of those whose hearts were perfect toward him.
2. God the Son is known primarily through his actions as the incarnated Jesus of Nazereth.  According to John, he existed from the beginning of Creation, and he made all things. By him there is nothing made that was made. He chose to temporarily give up the rights of godhood in order to become a man. Being found in human likeness, he was obedient unto death, even the death of a cross.
3. God the Holy Spirit is known primarily through his actions in the church.  God the Son sent Him to dwell amongst his people, and was most visibly manifest at Pentecost. He is the source of the gifts manifest amongst Christians and is present in His church.

None of these actors acts out of accord with any of the others, and they all have the same character and purpose. They do have unique wills, but willingly subordinate them to each other in perfect harmony.

The truth is there is no analogy because there is no terrestrial equivalent. That said, both Muslims and Christians would agree that God is so far above humans that his Nature could be incomprehensible to his creation. That God is both Three *and* One is the core tenet of our understanding of who God is. In no way do Christians believe there is more than one God, but how we express that remains a paradox we cannot or have not resolved since his nature was revealed.

Comment: `In no way do Christians believe there is more than one God, but how we express that remains a paradox we cannot or have not resolved since his nature was reveled.` helps just a bit and I will explore more on the topic. Thanks for your answer

Comment: If you refer to God as one _nature_ rather than one "being" then an analogy is simpler.  We all share the same _created nature_ yet we are distinct persons.  God is the _uncreated nature_ yet distinct persons.

Comment: Great answer, but I would suggest two edits. The Son did not temporary give up the rights of Godhood. The mystery of the incarnation, defended to the death for 2000 years, is that Jesus is simultaneously fully human **and** fully God. It is precisely *because* of this that humanity is bridged into heaven. I might also add that trinitarian language is intentionally confusing: We cannot fully comprehend God, who is Himself a relationship of three.

Comment: @svidgen  I agree, but wasn't really sure how to phrase that.  I was alluding to Phillippians 2 5 -12 there...

Answer (score 3):

**It is as complex as God:**

Just as Theists are unable to give logical explanation to Atheists about the existence of God, so is the case with Christians, where it is impractical to give a logical explanation of Triune nature of God because that which is being attempted to explain (in both instances) refer to same Entity called God. The concept of Trinity is as enigmatic as the existence of God and it is obviously so, because ultimately we are discussing about the same God.

The "Trinity" is an expression used to articulate one of many attributes of one and only one God based on the various references found woven through all of Scripture from Genesis to Revelation, which is why the doctrine was formulated. There is equally clearly only one true God in the Bible. Numerous references are available for both. It is simple logic to end up with the Trinity, although how it works in practice must remain to a degree a mystery, since if we fully understood God in His entirety, He would not be God.

The search for proof of existence of God is inconceivable in our finite mind and beyond the ability of limited conception of human intelligence & imagination. With this presumption, we get our belief in God and same is true for Trinity since with Trinity we are trying to define same God. In other words just like you cannot define God by your logical and scientific mind, the same is true of Trinity because we are trying to define the same God.

You and I are individual personalities, just like every other god of the major religions. The idea of the Trinity has plurality Within unity, a composite unity. This isn’t saying there is more than one God.

**Way out for accepting it:**

For Atheist it is the non-belief in (existence) God that keeps him from becoming a theist. For theist it is the “constituents, frame and state” of mind, not the proof, which makes him accept the belief in existence of God. However, in some cases with a presupposed mind, like a person with Islamic background, it does prevent them from accepting the Christian faith because of his inability to accept Trinity in the same “constituents, frame and state” of mind as he is accepting the existence of God.

**Trinity is woven in scriptures:**

Some argues that when it is not specifically stated anywhere in the Bible about the triune nature of God then why to formulate a Doctrine for it? Why not live and practice Christianity without it?

The answer lies in the truth that one cannot be a follower of Jesus if you do not believe in what He said and preached. When Jesus came into this world and preached the Good News about God’s kingdom, the true nature of One Almighty God was also revealed. Most obvious and direct evidence for Trinity emanated from Bible, depicting Jesus Christ and Holy Spirit with Nature of God. Therefore, if Father is God, Son is God and Holy Spirit is God than that’s it. Bible gives us irrefutable references about these claims in amorphous manner in OT and explicitly in NT. It was amorphous in OT, the reason being that it never became that clear until the Son was revealed in NT.

The central issue is, do we believe the Word of God? Despite what many non-Christians believe, Christians – (Mainstreams Christians) – believe that there is only one God. Yes, the Trinity is an odd doctrine, and many don’t like it. But who would make it up? We humans like things to make sense. Only the Trinity is an idea so odd that even after two millennia we still can’t properly understand it.

That there is one God, and yet, someone, there are three personalities who are deity, and yet there aren’t three gods but one. It sounds weird, crazy even. Does it seem that humans would make something like that up, or that the devil would? Satan knows that we like things to make sense; he wouldn’t create such a puzzling doctrine, neither would we humans and St. Constantine included.

Answer (score -1):

Is the concept of God in Christianity (the Trinity) three Gods or One

Yours is an age old question, which stems from a basic misunderstanding.

We have one God in three persons, but that is confusing unless we also understand that God is a Spirit. To explain that we must also understand the difference between the Spiritual realm and the Material realm.

In our material realm certain rules apply which do not apply in the Spiritual realm. For example; in the Material realm things have mass, which means that according to the laws of physics two objects cannot occupy the same space at the same time; that is not true in the Spiritual realm. The following Scripture shows this as effectively as anything I could say:

All scripture is quoted from the King James translation, unless otherwise noted.

> Mark 5:2 through 10  And when he was come out of the ship, immediately there met him out of the tombs a man with an unclean spirit,  3  Who had his dwelling among the tombs; and no man could bind him, no, not with chains: 4  Because that he had been often bound with fetters and chains, and the chains had been plucked asunder by him, and the fetters broken in pieces: neither could any man tame him. 5  And always, night and day, he was in the mountains, and in the tombs, crying, and cutting himself with stones. 6  But when he saw Jesus afar off, he ran and worshipped him, 7  And cried with a loud voice, and said, What have I to do with thee, Jesus, thou Son of the most high God? I adjure thee by God, that thou torment me not. 8  For he said unto him, Come out of the man, thou unclean spirit. 9  And he asked him, What is thy name? And he answered, saying, My name is Legion: for we are many. 10  And he besought him much that he would not send them away out of the country.

Here we see that many spirits were inhabiting the body of one man, and if we continue with the Scripture we find that there were about two thousand of them.

> Mar 5:11 through 13  Now there was there nigh unto the mountains a great herd of swine feeding. 12  And all the devils besought him, saying, Send us into the swine, that we may enter into them. 13  And forthwith Jesus gave them leave. And the unclean spirits went out, and entered into the swine: and the herd ran violently down a steep place into the sea, (they were about two thousand;) and were choked in the sea.

We also need to look at the words, Jesus said " What is thy name?" and the devils answered, 
" My name is Legion: for we are many."

It is noteworthy that Jesus used the singular form 'thy' in asking the name, and it is likewise notable that the devils (plural) used the singular form 'my' in answering even though adding that they were many.

There is no difference between those many spirits being one (legion) and God being three; Father, son, and Holy Ghost.

In the Spiritual realm more than one can occupy the same space at the same time, and be known by a single name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The Trinity is the teaching that there are "three persons in one Godhead."

**The GODHEAD**

The Greek word *theotetos* denotes “the state of being God.”

This is literally translated in English as “Godhead” (God-ness/God-hood).

> **Colossians 2:9 (KJV)**
>
> In him dwells all the fullness of the **Godhead** bodily

The nature of God is not material but spiritual (John 4:24) and hence, it is indivisible (without any parts).

**ONE GOD**

The Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit are not three Gods because of their one spiritual nature. These three persons possess the whole nature of being God. The reason is that the divine nature cannot be divided. We humans possess a nature that is immaterial per se and hence, divisible.

Man has one nature and yet we call individual persons collectively as “humans” because their one nature is divisible (has parts) but we cannot call the Trinity as “gods” (plural) because the name 'god' signifies the nature of the persons and that nature is singular and spiritual (without parts and hence, indivisible).

Hence, it is not just the issue of one nature but also of what kind of one nature are we talking about. It is something that is an indivisible unit or divisible? Is it flesh or spirit? In other words, this goes to the question of is it of the Creator or of the creature?

Furthermore, the name of the Trinity signifies God's oneness just as the name of Adam and Eve signifies their oneness.

> **Matthew 28:19 (NIV)**
>
> Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in
>   **the name** *of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit*,
>
> **Genesis 5:2 (KJV)**
>
> *Male and female* created he them; and blessed them, and called *their*
>   **name Adam**, in the day when they were created.

NOTE

In the Hebrew Text, the Shema literaly reads: "Hear O Israel YHWH our Gods [are] one YHWH."

So, here we see that YHWH is both singular and plural.

References:

http://www.gotquestions.org/Godhead.html

http://www.christiananswers.net/q-eden/edn-t002.html

https://carm.org/questions/about-god/does-deuteronomy-64-shema-disprove-trinity