# Blaspheme one part of the Trinity but not the whole?

Tags: biblical-basis, pneumatology, blasphemy, trinity

**Luke 12:10 NIV**

> And anyone who speaks a word against the Son of Man, it will be
>   forgiven him; but to him who blasphemes against the Holy Spirit, it
>   will not be forgiven

How is it possible to blaspheme the Son of Man but not the Holy Spirit since the trinity is one?

Comment: I feel I may have already answered this question to a degree on another post. At least gave my take on it your welcome to check it out. God bless. http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/28141/can-two-or-more-agree/28149#28149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Trinitarian principles, there is one God who reveals himself in three persons. One way to think of this is as a coin, where the front, the back, and the surface around the circumference are three distinct views of the coin. One can act against one view, making a mark on the front without affecting the other two. In like manner one can act against one person of the Trinity without acting against the other.

Note two that this saying of Jesus appears two other places, in Matthew (12:31-32), and in Mark (3:28-30). In two of the places it occurs, Jesus is speaking with his disciples, but in Mark he seems to be making a reference to the Pharisees.

Answer (score 2):

While the three persons of the Trinity are one God, they are three persons. If it is possible to talk about one of the persons alone (and it clearly is) then it is also possible to blaspheme against only one.

Comment: +1 However, it's a little confusing since 3 = 1.  The doctrine of the trinity isn't saying, "these are arms and legs of the body" but rather, "these three entities are the same entity."  Therefore, saying something about one *should* be the same as saying it to the other.  It's like saying that I worship the God Head but NOT Jesus and if that's okay... that opens up a door to pandora's box.

Comment: Of course you can say things about one person of the trinity, for example "Jesus is human."

Comment: @TheFreemason: Trinitarian teaching is not that 3 = 1, which is a wholly confusing idea. It's that God is one *nature* with three *persons*. See http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity/2049#2049. In short, the way God is one is different from the way in which he is three.

Comment: @LawrenceDol Your comment [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/28330/blaspheme-one-part-of-the-trinity-but-not-the-whole#comment69977_28332) appears to contradict your statement above (not the 3 persons part, but the "not that 3=1")

Comment: @TheFreemason: No it doesn't, I said exactly the same thing. (Being = nature = essense) != person. In other words, the way in which God is one is distinct and separate from the way in which he is three. Confusion arises from people thinking that God is `3x` and `1x`, when in fact Trinitarian doctrince is that he is `3x` and `1y`. The Nicene creed clarifies this when it says Jesus is "true God from true God, begotten, not made, one in being with the Father".

Answer (score -1):

Treading lightly here, and having no intentions of offending anyone.

The "trinity" is not found anywhere in the Bible, yet there are many scriptures which show that God the Father, Jesus Christ, and The Holy Spirit are three distinct beings, one  example of this is at Christ's baptism. Christ is baptized, God's voice is heard from the Heavens, and the Holy Spirit descended as a dove. Three distinct beings.

With that understanding, it is easy to see that you can blaspheme the Son of Man, but the Holy Spirit.

Comment: The questioner isn't asking for the views of non-Trinitarians on this, since it clearly isn't an issue for them.

Comment: When I answered the question, there were two tags, and trinitarian was not one of them, only these two tags: pneumatology, blasphemy -- If the other two were there, I would have refrained from answering. -- hence also why I stated I was treading lightly with no intention of offending anyone.

Comment: The original version of the question says "since the Trinity is one".

Comment: @staples while I may understand your point and share in similar beliefs, the question did say, "since the Trinity is one" as DJClayworth pointed out.  I added the tag after your posted for further clarification but it should have been obvious that I was looking for a trinitarian perspective.  Again, this is not a knock on your beliefs but rather the scope of the question.

Comment: Just by the way, Trinitarian doctrine is not that God is three distinct *beings*. It teaches that God is one *being* (or *essense*, or *nature*) and three *persons*.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have anything I can back this up with, but I learned that the unforgivable sin was to say that God cannot forgive you.  You have a free will so God will not force his forgiveness on you.  People usually commit this sin by denying the fact that they sin or thinking that they sinned so badly God would not forgive them.

Answer (score -3):

"God is one" refers to the fact that all angels from heaven, and all 7 Spirits of God, the Father, and Christ, are one in that they agree with one another and there is a chain of authority that is upheld by all parts of God.

You can blaspheme angels as well, and you aren't supposed to. (Jude)

You can declare that God deceived you, and according to Ezekiel 14:9, God might destroy you for that, but that isn't an unforgivable sin according to most interpretations.

sinning against one part of God isn't the same as another.

Comment: What the what?? "God is one" is talking about angels??? What branch of Christianity does this answer represent, because it doesn't represent Trinitarianism!

Comment: yes, God is one is talking about the angels that still work for him as well.

Comment: proof that God sends angels to speak to man? that's in half a dozen places.
as for proof angels cannot act on their own free will, that's a case i'd ask you to prove that they can. the angels that sinned are in hell. we know what sin is.

Comment: No, please provide references that "God is one" is talking about angels. I've never heard of that in any type of Christianity before.

Comment: In the context I argued, "God is one" means there is one God and he is consistent with himself, this includes all sentient creatures acting in God's will. Angels don't act on their own authority. we don't have lots of little 'g'ods as the pagans do, which was likely the context of those verses as well. 
Romans 3:30 however is showing that there is one God of all creation, not many gods for different races and religions. this verse would only relate to self consistency if all men were created equal, which is not proven either.

Comment: Yes. Please tell us who uses the phrase "God is one" to mean all of that. I have only ever heard of it as a statement about the Trinity, not all of creation.

Comment: I've not heard even heard it applied to the Trinity, only understood it in the context of destroying the pagan idea that there are many little 'g'ods, each with their own kingdom to play with.