# The Trinity as one being of one substance

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-god, trinity

Is there scripture in the Bible that says that God is one being of one substance, as taught by the Nicene and Athanasian creeds and philosophies of men?

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity?rq=1

Comment: That's not a summary of the definition of the Trinity. Simply put, God is one essence (or "being") and three hypostases/persons (μία οὐσία καὶ τρεῖς ὐποστάσεις).

Comment: John 10:30 is one verse.